# Git branch is at the same state as origin when I checkout to master

Tags: git

After working on a feature branch and also successfully setting my PR, I usually switch back to master. `git checkout master` gives me when checking out: Switched to branch "master". Your branch is at the same level as 'origin/master'.

Then when I do a git pull, git pulls down all the new changes on master and merges them into my local master.

```
Step 1: git checkout master
Step 2: git pull
```

But why does well tell me at step 1. that it is up to date with the origin? But in step 2 it fetches and merges the new changes. According to my understanding, it would be yes then not up to date!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `git checkout master` git will not automatically make a network request to check the remote server state. It merely checks the caches and the history tree available locally to you.

However, if you happen to `git pull --all` while in the feature branch and there were changes pushed to the remote, only then git will report that your local `master` branch is behind `origin/master` when you `git checkout master` .

Comment: Note the `--all` isn't necessary here, since all it does is fetch all *remotes*. Just `git pull` or `git fetch` by itself will fetch all *branches* on your current remote.